# Error while trying to install 'pymongo' libary

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip, pymongo

I tried to run my code on Linux ad get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

then I install with these commands :

> $ pip install pymongo

> $ pip install pymongo==2.1.1

> $ pip install --upgrade pymongo

and still get an error :

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pymongo/

I've tried to search this error - specific on 'pynomgo' and couldn't find anything.

I'd be happy if anyone can help me here.

thank you in advance.

Comment: During installation may be it is not connected to internet try again

Answer (score 0):

Please do check your internet connection.
Because the error says read timed out which meant there is a problem in internet connectivity.
If you still can't resolve the problem Please tell which OS you are using.
Because in linux based OS pymongo will be pre-installed.